# Error when get url name of images?

Tags: php

I have a code download image from link http://www.bitrepository.com/download-image.html
When start is link format: `<img src='test[1].jpg'>`
But when download this link is link become `<img src='test3%5B1%5D.jpg'>`
How to fix it?

code here

```
<?php
include_once 'class.get.image.php';

// initialize the class
$image = new GetImage;
$image->source = 'http://test.com/test[1].jpg';
$image->save_to = 'images/'; // with trailing slash at the end

$get = $image->download('gd'); // using GD

if($get)
{
echo 'The image has been saved.';
}
?>
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your code if "test3%5B1%5D.jpg" is the urlencoded value as that "3" shoudn't be there. or was your variable name "test3"? Maybe paste parts of the code you have tried.

Comment: are you sure this is correct ? `test[1].jpg` (not `$test[1].jpg` )?

Comment: just run urldecode()on the result

Comment: Just leave it as it is. That's the valid encoding. Also what is that cumbersome class for? Why not just `copy('http://test.com/test[1].jpg', 'images/test[1].jpg')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
On this line

```
$image->source = 'http://test.com/test[1].jpg';
```

Changed to

```
$image->source = htmlspecialchars_decode('http://test.com/test[1].jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up urldecode in php to change the encoded values back to brackets